# MongoDB $and on two columns

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am following MongoDB documentation for C# & shell commands to understand `find()` for `$and` for **restaurants** example. However, following issue I observed:

`ar builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("cuisine", "Italian") & builder.Eq("address.zipcode", "10075");`

filters the **restaurants** collection however when I change filter as:

`var filter = builder.Eq("borough", "Manhattan") & builder.Eq("cuisine", "American");`

This doesn't return any record as I can see combination of these two are present in **restaurants** collection.

**Shell** command which is not working:
`db.restaurants.find( { $and: [ {borough: "Queens" }, { cuisine: "American" } ] } )`

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Yo don't need to use the **$and** operator in this case.

`db.restaurants.find({borough: "Queens", cuisine: "American"})`

Only use **$and** operator when you need to specify more than one condition for the same field (i.e: `db.restaurants.find( { $and: [ {score:{$gte:5}},  {score:{$lte:10}} ] } )`)

Comment: Unfortunately, the one you suggested is also not working,as I tried it earlier. It simply shows me command prompt again.


`> db.restaurants.find({borough: "Queens", cuisine: "American"})

>`

Comment: If you are using the restaurants.json datasets (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/primer-dataset/dataset.json) note that the `American` cuisine is followed by a blank space. Try the following one: `db.restaurants.find({borough: "Queens", cuisine: "American "})` or `db.restaurants.find({borough: "Queens", cuisine:  { $regex: /^American/ }})` to match those documents which `cuisine` that start with `American`